# Kotlin GoogleSignInClient StartActivityForResult returns RESULT_CANCELED on one computer, but not another

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-signin

I have a login Google sign-in login for Firebase made pretty much like this:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
    private lateinit var signInButton: SignInButton
    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    private lateinit var signInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // never comes here
            textView.text = "Login result " + result.resultCode.toString()
        }
        else
            textView.text = "Login result " + result.resultCode.toString()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        var gso: GoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        textView = binding.textView
        signInButton = binding.signInButton
        signInButton.setOnClickListener {
            launcher.launch(signInClient.signInIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

It's been working fine on my main development computer, but I wanted to do some coding on another computer of mine too, so I copied the whole project to the other one. However, when I run the project on the second computer, it gets stuck by always getting RESULT_CANCELED when I click the sign-in button. What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried to use the new way of implementing [Firebase sign-in with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)? If you're willing to use Jetpack Compose, then this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: The issue isn't with my code. There's something off about how Android Studio is building my app and not using the correct keys or something like that. I copied the keystore from my main development computer to the other one and the SHA's from signin report match, but it still doesn't work. I added some different kind of debug code and the error I'm getting is "10: Developer console is not set up correctly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the answer in my comment to Alex's comment, but didn't realize it. Copying the debug.keystore from my main development computer to the other one, wiping the emulator and restarting Android Studio did the trick. I think initially I didn't do the wipe which was causing me the issues.